# Field with numbers and letters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which i have a field that requires 3 letters and 3 numbers (that have to between the values 2000 & 7000).

I've been reading around, and i'm still not sure which is the better way to handle this issue, whether it can be with a simple datatype, say for instance char(6), or if there has to be a field that contains only the 3 letters, and another field that contains the 3 numbers with a check restriction to ensure that the values of that field are between 2000 & 7000.

Any help that you can offer me, i would be glad. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand - how can you have values between 2000 and 7000 with only 3 numbers(/digits)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to give more specificity about the requirements, but it sounds to me like a single column is the best option -- especially if order matters.  If the letters and numbers have meanings separately, then they should be in two columns.  Otherwise, you'll just end up having to concatenate them together.

`char(6)` is fine as long as you know it will *always* be 6 characters exactly.  You can't enforce such a specific limit as 2000 to 7000 at column level anyway (which is 4 numbers, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

Every field should represent an attribute of the entities the table holds. In other words, if these three letters and three numbers represents different attributes, they should be in separate fields, otherwise (e.g. they are to represent a serial number) you can have them in one field. 
Another approach is to think of a possible use case, like: Am I going to perform a query based on the second number? If your answer is yes, then they should be in separate fields, otherwise they represent one attribute and they should be in one field.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is "one" value, use one column, say `char(6)`, but...

Here's a surprising fact: **mysql doesn't support CHECK constraints!**

Mysql allows CHECK constraints to defined, however they are completely ignored and allowed only for comparability with SQL from other databases.

If you want to enforce a format, you'll need to use a trigger, but mysql doesn't support raising exceptions, so you'll have to use a work-around.

The best option is probably to use app code for validation.